# iTerm2 mouse reporting outputting symbols

Tags: zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

Sometimes, for a reason I don't understand, mouse reporting prints those characters in the console uppon scolling clicking etc.

If I disable then re-enable mouse reporting then scrolling and clicking comes back as expected.

How do I debug the source of this "switch"? I don't  even know where to start  to understand what might happen in my console for this so happen.

[image]

local (remote) setup: zsh 5.7.1 (5.4.2) + oh-my-zsh (latest as of today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not been able to figure out what *triggered* this weird behaviour but 2 simple simple fixes are

- turn on/off **mouse reporting** in the preferences
- re-source `~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 2):

Just press cmd+R. It fixed the problem for me